# TweepError On Simple Tweepy Bot Retweeting Private List

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

So I'm making a simple Tweepy bot that retweets tweets from the account's private Twitter list. The bot seems to be working on Twitter, but it still throws me this error in the terminal:

```
  File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
    api.retweet(tweet.id)
  File "/Users/username/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 245, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/Users/username/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 229, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'code': 327, 'message': 'You have already retweeted this tweet.'}]
```

Any ideas? I'm also working on clearing the list where I'm storing all previous retweets once the list becomes too large. Thanks!

Here's the code:

```
tweets = api.list_timeline('username', 'username-list')
tweeted = []

while True:
    for tweet in tweets:
        if tweet.id not in tweeted:
            api.retweet(tweet.id)
            tweeted.append(tweet.id)
        elif tweet.id in tweeted:
            pass
```

Comment: I don't seem to get an error now after I've put the code in a function and called it. Any ideas why?